# Do the “Print to PDF” / “Save to PDF” options embed fonts in the PDF file?

Tags: pdf, preview, ms-office, font

Specifically:

- When doing this within the MS Office suite (Powerpoint, Word etc.), does the font get embedded within the PDF?
- Does Preview.app embed fonts when “Saving as PDF”?
- If I’m generating the PDF on a Mac, when I view it on other Macs and PCs, would the fonts be embedded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes to all your questions. OS X’ Quartz PDFContext generator embeds fonts ([unless the font forbids it, it seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2261031)). I couldn’t find any document that expressly states this (it’s implied in [this bit of Pages help](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Pages/4.0/en/sl1558b5cc.html), for instance) but I have been sending out PDF proofs with fonts not installed on the recipient’s computer long enough to know it does.

As long as you use the OS X routines for PDF generation, i.e. go through either the “Save as PDF” dialog or an option upstream of that, like Pages’ “Export” dialog, your fonts will be embedded – Microsoft’s Office suite is no exception. Anything that uses its own PDF generation routines (like [OpenOffice/LibreOffice/NeoOffice do with their “Export” option](http://neowiki.neooffice.org/index.php/Methods_of_Exporting_PDF_compared)), however, might or might not embed fonts, depending on its settings.

Finally, as already stated, “embedded” means “contained in the file”, which in turn means “viewable on other computers without the font installed”.

Comment: informative and pertinent answer. Cheers!

Comment: This workflow has the unintended side-effect of removing the hyperlinked bookmarks/table of contents. Is there any way to embed the fonts in a PDF on OS X without also removing the bookmarks?

Comment: @Nathaniel I’m not sure I understand the question: what workflow do you mean? Using macOS’ builtin PDF generator to create PDFs from non-PDF documents?

Answer (score 0):

Once the pdf is in preview, chose print, and then "PDF" from the Print Dialog.

There saying Save as PDF should embed the font. At least it worked for a pdf created from LaTeX for me.